# is Django AdminForm missing has_changed?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

Hi I'm very new to Django, and expect I'm missing something simple, so please bear with me.

I am encountering a 500 error when trying to save data on an admin page.

We are using grapelli-nested-inlines (https://github.com/datahub/grappelli-nested-inlines) on this page.

When I make the text change to a TextField, I receive this error:

```
AttributeError at /_admin/...
'InlineAdminFormSet' object has no attribute 'has_changed'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/_admin/...
Django Version: 1.7.4
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'InlineAdminFormSet' object has no attribute 'has_changed'
Exception Location: venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/grappelli_nested/forms.py in <genexpr>, line 36
Python Executable:  venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.4.3
Python Path:    
['venv/lib/python34.zip',
 'venv/lib/python3.4',
 'venv/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
 'venv/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/plat-darwin',
 'venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 13 Aug 2015 15:24:08 +0000
```

InlineAdminFormSet is defined in https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/helpers.py as an AdminForm.

Based on the Django docs I would expect all forms to have the has_changed method defined, but this one doesn't seem to.

I don't see anyone else referencing this issue, so that leads me to believe I'm missing something.

Can someone please clarify for me:

1. Should AdminForm have a has_changed method (if so how do I go about pushing that in?)
2. if not should I just handle this in a fork of grapelli?
3. or is there some other solution I'm missing.

Cheers

Comment: Could you post the full traceback, and the code that is causing the error? It might make it clearer what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

`AdminForm` and `InlineAdminFormSet` are undocumented internals. They do not inherit from `forms.Form`, so they don't have a `has_changed` method.

You could try opening an issue for [grappelli-nested-inlines](https://github.com/datahub/grappelli-nested-inlines/issues), or dig deeper into the internals and try to figure it out.

Comment: I've made the fixes necessary locally, but little confused as to the process.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that I was seeing things correctly.  Thanks.